# SAS: how to concatenate column b to column a when there are multiple rows per group in column a?

Tags: sas

The original table looks as below:

```
data have;
input group_id $3.visit $4. week $3.;
cards;
111 v1 .  
111 v2 w4 
111 v3 w8 
111 v4 w12 
111 v4 w16 
111 v4 w20 
111 v5 w24 
111 v5 w28 
111 v5 w32 
111 v5 w36 
222 v1 .   
222 v2 w4 
222 v3 w8 
222 v4 w12 
222 v4 w16 
222 v4 w20 
222 v5 w24 
222 v5 w28 
222 v5 w32 
222 v5 w36 
run;
```

Since there have multiple rows with some groups in column visit, I'd like to process the column week and then concatenate it to column visit as below:

| group_id | visit | visit(week) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | v1 | v1 |
| 111 | v2 | v2(w4) |
| 111 | v3 | v3(w8) |
| 111 | v4 | v4(w12-w20) |
| 111 | v5 | v5(w24-w36) |
| 222 | v1 | v1 |
| 222 | v2 | v2(w4) |
| 222 | v3 | v3(w8) |
| 222 | v4 | v4(w12-w20) |
| 222 | v5 | v5(w24-w36) |

But I have no clue to write the code in SAS. Thanks very much for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code:

```
proc sort data=have out=have_sorted;
/* make sure you weeks in order or ensure alphabetical order */
  by group_id visit /* week */;
run;

data res;
  length visit_week first_week $200;
  retain first_week;
  drop first_week week;

  set have_sorted;
  by group_id visit;
  if first.visit then do;
    first_week = week;
    if last.visit then do;
      if missing (week) then
        visit_week = visit;
      else
        visit_week = cats (visit, '(', week, ')');
      output;
    end;
  end;
  else if last.visit then do;
    visit_week = cats (visit, '(', first_week, '-', week, ')');
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Result:

```
v1  111 v1
v2(w4)  111 v2
v3(w8)  111 v3
v4(w12-w20) 111 v4
v5(w24-w36) 111 v5
v1  222 v1
v2(w4)  222 v2
v3(w8)  222 v3
v4(w12-w20) 222 v4
v5(w24-w36) 222 v5
```